# Windows Terminal isn't added to tab history when started via the Run dialog

Tags: windows-11, alt-tab, windows-terminal

When opening `powershell`, `cmd`, `bash`, or any other REPL from the Run dialog (Win + R) via the Windows Terminal app ("WT" from now on), I can type as though WT's focused, but its taskbar icon isn't highlighted like it would normally be if a window is in focus, indicating to me that Windows doesn't actually realize that it's in focus.

The issue arises when I use `Alt + Tab` to switch to another app and use `Alt + Tab` again to switch back to WT. When that happens, I'd expect WT to be focused again, but instead it puts WT in the last position, so I end up switching to the second-most recent app instead of back to WT. Is there anything I can do to make Windows properly add it to the `Alt + Tab` menu history when launched from the Run dialog?

---

| OS | Version | Build | Architecture |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 11 Pro | 22H2 | 22624.1537 | 64 bit |

Comment: You can follow this problem at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/15763

Answer (score 1):

Can you file a bug over at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal? This sounds like a Terminal issue. There's [microsoft/terminal#13388](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/13388), but that sounds... different. There was something vaguely similar to what you're describing, but I think that was fixed in the v1.15 timeframe of the Terminal (so that shouldn't really be happening anymore).

Comment: I agree that this sounds a bit different than #13388. Sure thing, I'll submit an issue.